# Get dojo methods for a DOM element

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have 'this' pointing to a DOM element ( a `div` or a `form` ). I want to use dojo functions over that element. How will I do it.

Like in jQuery we do `$(this).append()` ....

is there anything like

```
dojo.foo(this).connect()
```

or

```
dojo.connect(dojo.foo(this),"some", thing);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Dojo, you are much closer to JavaScript (the **raw metal**) than in jQuery.

So in Dojo, you just do:

```
dojo.connect(this, ...);
```

You don't have to "wrap" the DOM element with a class object (like jQuery's $) to use the functionalities.  A lot of functionalities in Dojo are not exposed as prototype properties of a class object, but as simple functions under the dojo.xxx namespace system.

For example (assume "this" points to a DOM node):

```
dojo.connect(this, "onclick", foo, "bar");   // Connects a handler to the Click event on the DOM node, with the context (i.e. this) set to the object foo
dojo.attr(this, "href", "http://www.hello.com");   // Sets an attribute on the DOM node
dojo.style(this, "display", "none");   // Sets the DOM node's style
dojo.addClass(this, "hello");   // Adds a class to the DOM node
alert(this.parentNode);   // You work the DOM nodes with raw JavaScript
dojo.empty(this);  // Empty all children in the DOM node
dojo.destroy(this);  // Destroy the DOM node and its children
dojo.place(this, someOtherNode);   // Put a DOM node as a child inside another node
```

Looping constructs:

```
dojo.forEach(array, ...);   // Instead of array.each(...) as in jQuery style
```

If you want to loop through a list of nodes, it actually looks like jQuery:

```
dojo.query('query string').filter(...).forEach(...);
```

Read the docs for more details.

Comment: how to perform prev() and next() operations on a dom node using dojo.

Comment: I am not sure whether Dojo has these built-in features.  You may need to use JavaScript's nextSibling or previousSibling.

Comment: for functions like nextAll, prevAll, siblings, parents... then should we redefine in javascript while dojo has these natively

Comment: @Boopathi Rajaa, Dojo does not **replace** JavaScript.  It augments JavaScript by adding things that are not standard or not uniform across browsers.  For things that are standard across browsers, it leaves alone.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a way that will work i guess. Don't know if it is the best solution..

Have to import NodeList-traverse to use functions like children, parent ...
Reference: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/NodeList-traverse.html#dojo-nodelist-traverse

```
dojo.require("dojo.NodeList-traverse");
```

Reference: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/NodeList.html

```
var nl = new dojo.NodeList(this);

nl.parent();
```

Comment: +1 for posting the solution you found as an answer. That's the stackoverflow spirit :-) I'm actually not sure if there is a more "correct" solution - this is one of the areas where jquery feels more elegant. I do believe the Dojo devs have a reason for not mixing vanilla DOM nodes with enhanced "Dojo DOM nodes" though.

Comment: @Frode, I think they are different design philosophies.  Dojo is more the "procedural" style.  jQuery is more object-oriented and "functional" style.  Personally I think jQuery is more elegent, but Dojo avoids the performance penalties (at least in old browsers) in jQuery for constructing lots of jQuery objects...  Google's Closure Library, which was used to build industrial-scale web apps, is also procedural style for the same reasons.

Comment: Dojo is completly object-oriented, but not for this absolutly basics. If you do just this little stuff then jQuery can be easier. But if you start to build a complete RIA application then you see how OOP and powerfull Dojo is. And you probably don't use a lot of these low-level stuff that jQuery makes a little bit better. Actually i would say the other way around that jQuery is not really OOP. Just give the possibility to chain a lot of function does not make anything OOP.

Comment: If jQuery isnt really doing OO code, then can you tell me what does OOP in JavaScript mean ?. using the scope to create private and public methods and vars (abstracting data)... and giving ability to extend/inherit ... Is it not what OOP means in JS ??

Comment: @Sid Burn, you are absolutely correct.  Having one object in jQuery doesn't really make it OOP.  jQuery lacks a formal class-definition and inheritance mechanism, although there are numerous plugins that do the same.

Comment: @Boopathi Rajaa, JavaScript by itself is not OO to the strict sense (which contains the three characteristics of OOP systems), it uses "prototypical inheritance", not object-inheritance.  However, the features are so similar that you can probably call it OOP in a loose sense.  There are ways to "simulate" (or fake) an OOP layer over JavaScript.  Dojo provides this mechanism and you can write code that is very close to a true OOP system.  jQuery just does not have a formal mechanism, but rely on plugins.